# Efficent way to set date using week of month value

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, datetime, date

I have a week of month in sql and i need to generate a datetime varible from that.. fields i have are dayofweek, weekofmonth and month values. anyone know of a quick effective way to calculate this in mssql 2005? Thanks

Keep in mind. if week of month is set to 5 it is the last week of the month

Examples are i have DayOfWeek, month, year, weekofmonth..

so lets say i have DayOfWeek = 2 (monday)
                   month = 5 ( may)
                   year = 2009
                   weekofmonth = 5

i would expect monday may 25th 2009

DayOfWeek = 1, Month = 5, Week = 1, year = 2009 = Sunday, May 3rd 2009

DayOfWeek = 5, Month = 4, Week = 3, Year = 2009 = Thursday, April 16th 2009

Additional Info:

I am using the .net TimezoneInfo.TransitionTime class library to help me store some stuff in the db.. they say:

**The Month property defines the month in which the time change occurs. The Day property defines the day of the week on which the transition occurs. The Week property determines which week of the month the time change occurs in. Valid values of the Week property can range from 1 to 5. A value of 5 indicates the last week of the month.**

so far i have this:

```
declare @IsFixedDateRule    bit
declare @Day                tinyint
declare @DayOfweek          tinyint
declare @Week               tinyint
declare @Month              tinyint
declare @Year               int
declare @TimeofDay          int -- SECONDS

set @IsFixedDateRule = 0
set @Day = 1
set @DayOfweek = 1
set @Week = 5
set @Month = 4
set @year = 2008
set @TimeofDay = 7200

declare @date datetime

if (@IsFixedDateRule = 1)   
begin
    set @date = convert(char(4),@Year) + '/' + convert(char(2),@Month) + '/' + convert(char(2),@Day)  -- Set Year/Month
end
else
begin       
    set @date = convert(char(4),@Year)  + '/' + convert(char(2),@Month) + '/01' -- Set Year/Month

    declare @datepart tinyint
    set @datepart = datepart(weekday ,@date)    

    set @date = dateadd(week, @week - 1, dateadd(weekday, @Dayofweek - case when @datepart = 7 then 0 else @datepart end, @date))-- get the day

end

select dateadd(second, @TimeofDay,  @date) -- Add Time Of Day
```

anything cleaner?

Comment: provide some examples (multiple).  given x, y, z, result is g....

Comment: Can you post some more examples (f.e. what is dayofweek=1, weekofmonth=1, month=5, year=2009). And August has 6 weeks this year... is your 5th week like a maximum?  If it is, how would you denote August 31st, so that it's different from August 24th?

Comment: Sure.. your example would indicate sunday, may 3rd 2009.. ill edit my post to include more info

Comment: If the dayofweek=1, weekofmonth=1, month=5 is the 3rd of May, how do you indicate the 1st of May?

Comment: this example covers only dates that are not on fixed schedules.. fixed dates are handled much cleaner.. this usually handles dates like the 3rd wednesday of april.. ect. in your examples to get the first of may we would need to do.. month = 5 dayofweek = 6 (fri) week = 1 year = 2009

Comment: Actually, if you look at this month on the calendar, there are 6 weeks. Same goes for any month that starts on a Friday (with 31 days) or Saturday (with 30 or 31 days), assuming your week starts on a Sunday. WeekOfMonth == 5 won't necessarily be the last week of the month.

Answer (score 1):

This is fairly simple, and really just adds days and weeks to the first day of that month. It assumes you're using the current year, and won't really handle things like the 5th week of February. (Example: 5th week, 3rd day of February gives 03/11/2009)

```
DECLARE @CalculatedDate DATETIME;

-- Assuming DayOfWeek and WeekOfMonth are 1-based
SELECT @CalculatedDate = DATEADD(DAY, @DayOfWeek - 1, DATEADD(WEEK, @WeekOfMonth - 1, '2009-' + STR(@Month) + '-01'));

-- Assuming DayOfWeek and WeekOfMonth are 0-based
SELECT @CalculatedDate = DATEADD(DAY, @DayOfWeek, DATEADD(WEEK, @WeekOfMonth, '2009-' + STR(@Month) + '-01'))
```

It also assumes that DayOfWeek == 1 for the first day of the month, so it's almost definitely wrong. Can we see some sample data and expected outputs?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestiong.. works perfect except when weekofmonth is set to 5.. should be last week of the month.. this overflows to the next month

Answer (score 0):

The first week of May starts on Friday.   So what date would be dayofweek=1, weekofmonth=1, month=5?  Is that Monday April 27th?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** - amended to handle different values of `@@datefirst`

My guess based on the data available so far.

This will work if you SQL server installation has `@@datefirst` set to Sunday(7) or Monday(1).

The test data is set up to return 01-May-2009

```
declare @dayofweek int
declare @weekofmonth int
declare @month int
declare @datefirst_adjustment int


select @datefirst_adjustment = case @@datefirst when 1 then 0
                                                when 7 then 1
                               end

declare @firstofyear datetime

set @firstofyear = '20090101'

set @dayofweek = 5

set @month = 5

set @weekofmonth = 1


select dateadd(ww,@weekofmonth - 1,dateadd(mm,@month - 1,@firstofyear)) - datepart(dw,dateadd(mm,@month - 1,@firstofyear)) + @dayofweek + @datefirst_adjustment
```

Comment: dayofweek=1, weekofmonth=1, month=5 gives the 26th of April, which is a Sunday?

Comment: I got my @@datefirst values wrong. Edited the description to reflect this.

Comment: try this for april 2009 with weekofmonth = 5 should be april 26th ( week of 5 = last week of month ) ?? what do you get?

Comment: For month 4, week 5, day 1 I get 26 April. What value do you get for select @@datefirst?

Comment: hey.. select @@datefirst gives me 7

Comment: Revised to handle different values of @@datefirst. I tested this on two different servers which I hadn't realised (until now) has @@datefirst set to different values

Answer (score 0):

```
/* 
 * Assuming @year is this year
 *          @day_of_week starts from Sunday = 1, Monday = 2 etc
 */
declare @week_of_month int,
        @day_of_week int,
        @month int,
        @year int,
        @derived_date datetime

set dateformat dmy
select @year = datepart(year, getdate()),
       @day_of_week = 2,
       @week_of_month = 2,
       @month = 5


select @derived_date = convert(varchar,@year) + '-01-' + convert(varchar,@month) 
select @derived_date
select @derived_date = dateadd(dd, @day_of_week - datepart(dw, @derived_date), dateadd(week, @week_of_month-1,  @derived_date))
select @year, @month, @day_of_week, @week_of_month, @derived_date

/* Test */
declare @date datetime

set @date = '04-MAY-2009'
select @date, cast(datename(week,@date) as int)- cast( datename(week,dateadd(dd,1-day(@date),@date)) as int)+1 week_of_month, datepart(dw, @date) day_of_weekhere
```

Comment: -1 Ran this post and it gave many rows, none of which looked like a plausible answer (other than the hardcoded 4-may.)

Comment: My system is set to dateformat dmy which is british dates. I've edited the code to reflect this - please retry

Comment: Thanks, that'll teach me to test my code properly. I keep forgetting not everyone is a Brit :)

Comment: select @year = datepart(year, getdate()),
       @day_of_week = 6,
       @week_of_month = 5,
       @month = 6

this goes into july.. week 5 needs to be the last week in june.. should be june 26th.. maybe i can check and remove 1 week if the month isnt the same as the one passed in

if (datepart(month, @derived_date) <> @month)
 set @derived_date = dateadd(week, -1, @derived_date)